# SQL Select statement where = 'List'?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, list

I've never done something like this before and it works if I just pass a single integer to it, but I have a list I need to use for POSITION_ID.  The list has for example just 1,2,3..etc.  This throws an exception `The specified object must not be an instance of a generic type` from `ExecuteParameterQuery`. I'm not sure if/how to do this when a list is involved.

**Changes made from help.**

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> SelectedLineHistory(string partProgram, string machineId, List<int> Line2, bool orderByDate = false)

{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> results = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    string query = "SELECT MACHINE_ID, PART_PROGRAM, POSITION_ID, DATE_TIME, SAVE_DATE_TIME,DWELL_STIME, ADJUSTED_AMOUNT, DWELL_OFFSET, EMPL_ID " +
                   "FROM MPCS.WJ_DWELL_OFFSETS_HIST " +
                   "WHERE PART_PROGRAM = ? and MACHINE_ID = ? and POSITION_ID = ? ";
    if (orderByDate)
    {
        query += " order by save_date_time desc, position_id asc";
    }

    List<OleDbParameter> queryParameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();

    foreach (var line in Line2)
    {
        queryParameters.Clear();
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("PART_PROGRAM", partProgram));
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("MACHINE_ID", machineId));
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", Line));

        results = this.ExecuteParameterQuery(query, queryParameters);
    }
    return (results);
}
```

---

I error if I don't use `results = this.ExecuteParameterQuery(query, queryParameters);` instead of `results.add` but I don't think that's my problem here.

It still produces the original error `The specified object must not be an instance of a generic type`

And this is the way I call it.  Which again worked prior to needing to use the list for positionID

I'm still trying to figure out what I have to make 'new' as suggested but just haven't discovered it yet but wanted to keep this updated.

```
public void SelectedHistory(bool showMessages = false)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> resultHistory = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    string machineId = cboMachine.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
    string partProg = cboPartPrograms.Text.Trim().ToUpper();

    lvViewHistory.Items.Clear();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(machineId) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(partProg))
    {
        resultHistory = oracleConnection.SelectedLineHistory(partProg, machineId, Line2, true);

        if (resultHistory != null && resultHistory.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in resultHistory)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(d["MACHINE_ID"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["PART_PROGRAM"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["POSITION_ID"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["DATE_TIME"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["SAVE_DATE_TIME"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["DWELL_STIME"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["ADJUSTED_AMOUNT"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["DWELL_OFFSET"]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(d["EMPL_ID"]);

                lvViewHistory.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No History Found");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select Machine_Id and Part Program");
    }

    lvViewHistory.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
}
```

For whatever reason it works now, but instead of giving me results for however many line numbers are in line2, it just gives me the results from the last line number.

So if Line2 has 1,2,3 I should get sql results from all rows where line number is 1 2 and 3 instead I just get results where line number is 3.

Comment: You want to execute this once per `line` in `line2`, right?  Your query execution needs to be moved inside the loop for that to happen!

Comment: Your correct yes once per line number in line2

Comment: Read about using SQL where in clause. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: @STLDeveloper Edited, is that correct now?

Comment: @Hakunamatata Thank you I will see if that helps me out.

Comment: That being the case, the query execution needs to be moved up before the end of the `foreach` loop.  Then I assume you'd populate that result into the `Dictionary` it looks like you're planning to return.

Comment: @STLDeveloper That's correct, and all that works prior to finding out there would be a where clause of position ID's, and that messed up me all up trying to incorporate that.  I gotta leave the office for a bit, I'll be back.  Thank again.

Comment: Not quite.  The `return` in your loop will cause termination on the first iteration - you don't want that.  Instead, pull the results from your query and store it in your output list.

Comment: omniowner is correct in his answer below.  But you don't want to return until after executing for each item in the `line2` list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is what you're looking for.  Notice that it adds each iteration's results to the `result` List.  It also corrects the defect noted previously by @omniowner.

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> SelectedLineHistory(string partProgram, string machineId, List<int> Line2, bool orderByDate = false)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> results;
    string query = "";
    List<OleDbParameter> queryParameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();

    foreach (var line in Line2)
    {
        query = "SELECT MACHINE_ID, PART_PROGRAM, POSITION_ID, DATE_TIME, SAVE_DATE_TIME,DWELL_STIME, ADJUSTED_AMOUNT, DWELL_OFFSET, EMPL_ID ";
        query += "FROM MPCS.WJ_DWELL_OFFSETS_HIST ";
        query += "WHERE PART_PROGRAM = ? and MACHINE_ID = ? and POSITION_ID = ?";

        if (orderByDate)
        {
            query += " order by save_date_time desc, position_id asc";
        }

        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("PART_PROGRAM", partProgram));
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("MACHINE_ID", machineId));

        /* in the following parameter, use this iteration's value, line,  *
         * rather than the entire collection, Line2                       */
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", line));

        /**** this looks sketchy -- check it *****/
        results.Add(this.ExecuteParameterQuery(query, queryParameters));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Food for thought:  As written, this will execute one database query/round trip for each element in the Line2 list.  You may prefer to execute just one query, using a where clause that specifies each of the elements in Line2.  This would be much more efficient, but will take more code to prepare the results returned to this routine's caller.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is you are trying to pass the whole List of Integers in as a parameter in...

```
queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", Line2));
```

You should try changing this to just the item you are iterating on in the list. Like this...

```
queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", line));
```

You are also returning before you finish iterating through the entire list (as  STLDeveloper mentions in the question comments). You want to move that return statement out of your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from STL +1

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> 
SelectedLineHistory(string partProgram, string machineId, 
                    List<int> Line2, bool orderByDate = false)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> results = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    string query = "SELECT MACHINE_ID, PART_PROGRAM, POSITION_ID, DATE_TIME, SAVE_DATE_TIME,DWELL_STIME, ADJUSTED_AMOUNT, DWELL_OFFSET, EMPL_ID " +
                   "FROM MPCS.WJ_DWELL_OFFSETS_HIST " +
                   "WHERE PART_PROGRAM = ? and MACHINE_ID = ? and POSITION_ID = ? ";
    if (orderByDate)
    {
        query += " order by save_date_time desc, position_id asc";
    }

    List<OleDbParameter> queryParameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();

    foreach (var line in Line2)
    {
        //actually should define parameter outside the loop and just assign the value here
        queryParameters.Clear();
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("PART_PROGRAM", partProgram));
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("MACHINE_ID", machineId));
        queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", Line));

        results.Add(this.ExecuteParameterQuery(query, queryParameters));        
    }
    return (results);
}
```

Line2 is a List and you are still using it

```
queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", Line2));
```

try

```
queryParameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("POSITION_ID", Line));
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You are correct!  I think I've been on vacation too long!  @Lee - please see Paparazzi's answer for a more correct implementation of your function.

Comment: @Paparazzi Something about where `results.add` is located produces `Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'results'` And then `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>'`

Comment: @Lee will did you try newing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by newing it.  Also I posted above the changes I had to make just to not get error on the error list window so you can see that part.

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm sorry I didn't know what "newing" was as it didn't appear to be a word.  And I posted the changes I had to make to get rid of the error's I was getting that stopped me from even running the code.   Which puts me right back to the error I was getting that caused me to post this question in the first place.  So I'll add to the OP the way I'm calling all this and maybe that will help but if I knew where to look to correct this error I never would have posted.

Comment: @Paparazzi I changed where I'm calling it from my form to `List<Dictionary<string, string>> resultHistory = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();`  Is that what I needed, it didn't work but I wasn't sure if that needed done.